# Texture artifacts on seams area

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

why am I having such strange artifacts on my seams area? What's wrong with the UV unwrap or something else? Thanks in advance for your help.
[image]

Comment: Some more info might be helpful, such as what version of Blender you're using, if you've checked that all normals are facing out, and if you've verified there's no duplicated geometry (that's what looks likely from the screenshot). Also, it's sometimes a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem. The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files: blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: Looks like a problem with amount of bleed compounded with the effect of Occlude blocking at an angle. Painting closer in to the seam area and increasing the Bleed from 2 pixels to 4 or even 6 might help a bit.